# Ace Editor Losing Focus in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ace-editor

I am working on an app using the Ionic Framework and would like to include an ace editor component in an `<ion-view>`.

**Issue:**

*When I click within the the ace editor I can see it select the line but the cursor doesn't display.*

You can see the issue in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/wIfmy) (not my codepen but same issue exists)

The issue I am having appears to be that the ace editor keeps loosing focus but I can't seem to figure out what could be stealing the focus.  I think this is the issue because in the elements panel in chrome I can see that the following class is assigned to the div.

`ace_layer ace_cursor-layer ace_hidden-cursors`

Interestingly, If i hold down the mouse click a little longer it will gain focus and the cursor will display. Short mouse clicks don't work.

*My html template for the editor:*

```
<ion-view view-title="Editor">
  <ion-content>
    <div>
      <pre id="ace-editor">this is a test</pre>
    </div>  
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And my angular `controller` where i set the `ace editor`:

```
.controller('EditorCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
  var init = function () {
    editor = ace.edit('ace-editor');
    editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
    editor.setOption("dragEnabled", false);
    editor.removeAllListeners("mousedown");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");    
  };

  init();
});
```

I tried removing all `mousedown` events on the ace editor seeing if it was related that but it didn't fix.

I've also tried removing the `sidemenu` `drag` from the ionic side menu but that didn't fix either.

Comment: there is a tapMouseUp event listener added to document by ionic bundle, which blurs editor on mouseup

Answer (score 2):

Use `data-tap-disabled="true"` like this:

`<pre id="ace-editor" data-tap-disabled="true">this is a test</pre>`

I found it here: http://www.ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/

Comment: I had the same problem as you and now it works for me, but I'm using `div` instead of `pre`.